# Продублировать массив не самым простым способом

Tags: javascript, массивы

Задание:

> Создать функцию, которая принимает массив, а возвращает новый массив с
> дублированными элементами входного массива.
> Данное задание выполните
> после того как познакомитесь с методами массивов: doubleArray([1,2,3])
> // [1,2,3,1,2,3]

Решил его так:

```
function doubleArray(arr) {
  var result = [];
  var result = result.concat(arr).concat(arr);
  return result;
}
```

Но потом решил повозиться с циклическими операторами, но там консоль уходит в вечную загрузку

```
function doubleArray(arr) {
  let result = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    result[i] = arr[i];
  }

  for (let i = result.length; i < result.length * 2 - 1; i++) {
    result[i] = result[i - result.length];
  }
  return result;
}
console.log(doubleArray([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]));
```

Во втором коде пытаюсь подсчитать длину массива и если массив заканчивается, допустим, на пятом индексе, с шестого я пытаюсь в него записать значения 0 индекса массива, `arr[1] = arr[7]`, `arr[2] = arr[8]` и т.д.

В общем я так понимаю индексы и длина массива разные вещи и поэтому происходят несостыковки, но тем способом что я начал, можно ли решить задание?

```
function doubleArray(arr) {
  let result = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    result[i] = arr[i];
  }
  let l = arr.length;
  console.log(l);
  for (let i = l; i < l * 2; i++) {
    result[i] = result[i - l];
  }
  return result;
}
console.log(
  doubleArray([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16])
);
```

Comment: Запишите длину массива arr в переменную и используйте её

Comment: @MBo
получилось, спасибо. Сделал так
`let l = arr.length;`<br/>
 
  <br>for (let i = l; i < l * 2; i++) {<br/>
    result[i] = result[i - l];<br/>
 ` }`<br/>

Answer (score 1):

1. В первом варианте нет нужды создавать пустой массив, так как [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) и так возвращает новый массив. В итоге код функции станет таким:

   ```
   function doubleArray(arr) {
       return arr.concat(arr);
   }
   ```
2. Ошибка происходит из-за того, что условие `i < result.length * 2 - 1` проверяется на каждой итерации цикла, соответственно значение `result.length` каждый раз будет увеличиваться и цикл будет бесконечным.

---

Решений может быть несколько:

1. вынести конечное значение в переменную и использовать именно ее.
2. так как конечное число элементов известно, можно сразу выделить массив под нужное количество, в этом случае длина не будет меняться.

   ```js
   function doubleArray(arr) {
     let result = Array(arr.length * 2);
     for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
       result[i] = arr[i];
     }

     for (let i = arr.length; i < result.length; i++) {
       result[i] = result[i - arr.length];
     }
     return result;
   }
   console.log(doubleArray([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]));
   ```
3. вообще убрать второй цикл, добавляя по два элемента в нужные места

   ```js
   function doubleArray(arr) {
     let result = Array(arr.length * 2);
     for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
       result[i] = arr[i];
       result[i + arr.length] = arr[i];
     }

     return result;
   }
   console.log(doubleArray([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]));
   ```

Comment: ах да, то есть после каждого цикла я записывал новые значения в массив и из-за этого длина самого массива увеличивалась, а так как я его записал в условие, то увеличивалось и условие. Спасибо за разъяснение